# Lévy Continuity Theorem for continuous-time processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Usually, Lévy Continuity Theorem is stated for sequences of random variables, i.e. $$\varphi_{X_n}(\theta)\to \varphi_X(\theta)\Rightarrow X_n\xrightarrow{d}X.$$ However, can this result be extended for the case of a continuous random process, i.e. if we have $\varphi_{X_t}(\theta)\to \varphi_X(\theta)$ as $t\to \infty$, where $t\in\mathbb{R}_+$?

Comment: You did not quote Levy's theorem correctly. It must further hold that $\varphi_X(\theta)$ is continuous at $\theta = 0$.

Comment: If $X_t \to X$ a.s., then it automatically holds that $X_t \to X$ in distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representation of Lévy processes by the means of its characteristic function in the Lévy-Khintchine Representation gives you by unicity of such representation the tool to get convergence results (i.e. for a sequence of processes $X^n_t\to X_t$).

But your claim with $t\to \infty$ is simply wrong. For example for a Brownian motion it has no meaning, as the limit of $B_t$ as t goes to infinity does not exists.

Edit to answer the right question :
The claim is true if and only if for any sequence $t_n$ tending to infinity the limit exist and doesn't depend on the sequence, but by Lévy's continuity theorem and your hypothesis the limit exists and is the same whatever sequence you take.

Best regards

Comment: I assume that the limit exists. The case of a Brownian Motion is similar to a symmetric Random Walk, for which this limit does not exists as well...

Comment: For example $X_t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}B_t$ is $N(0,1)$ for all $t$...

Comment: @ Robert W. : Are you sure that there exists a such a Lévy process ? (I mean except for convergence to a constant). I mean your $X_t$ is not a Lévy process (increments are not stationary...). Best regards.

Comment: I didn't mean a Levy process. I meant the "Levy continuity theorem" which implies convergence in distribution of sequences of r.v.s...

Comment: @Robert W. : Sorry for the confusion I tried to answer a very different question. I get it now and the answer is "yes indeed", I'll edit my post. Best regards.